# How to convert JSON Http response to Array in AngularJS 2

Tags: arrays, json, angular, ionic-framework

I'm doing a Http get in Angular 2 and the response is a JSON. However, i'm trying to use this in a ngFor but i can't because it isn't an Array.

How can I convert JSON to Array in Angular 2? I searched in many websites but didn't discover a effective way to do that.

**Edit 1:**

The response is like that:

```
{
  "adult": false,
  "backdrop_path": "/fCayJrkfRaCRCTh8GqN30f8oyQF.jpg",
  "belongs_to_collection": null,
  "budget": 63000000,
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 18,
      "name": "Drama"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": "",
  "id": 550,
  "imdb_id": "tt0137523",
  "original_language": "en",
  "original_title": "Fight Club",
  "overview": "A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking new form of therapy. Their concept catches on, with underground \"fight clubs\" forming in every town, until an eccentric gets in the way and ignites an out-of-control spiral toward oblivion.",
  "popularity": 0.5,
  "poster_path": null,
  "production_companies": [
    {
      "name": "20th Century Fox",
      "id": 25
    }
  ],
  "production_countries": [
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "United States of America"
    }
  ],
  "release_date": "1999-10-12",
  "revenue": 100853753,
  "runtime": 139,
  "spoken_languages": [
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "name": "English"
    }
  ],
  "status": "Released",
  "tagline": "How much can you know about yourself if you've never been in a fight?",
  "title": "Fight Club",
  "video": false,
  "vote_average": 7.8,
  "vote_count": 3439
}
```

Comment: Do a `console.log` of the response and add it to the question.

Comment: @AndreaM16 Please, check Edit 1. Thk you.

Comment: @KodieGrantham Please note that i'm using AngularJS 2 and this question is based on AngularJS 1.

Comment: @LucasS.Müller Noted! Sorry about that!

Comment: Try with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: That response no is a JSON array, it's a complex object, you cannot cross it only as an array.

Comment: Array of what? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @iCediCe Convert that JSON Object to Array to use in ngFor.

Comment: What platform are you trying to do this with? The name for Angular 2 is Angular 2, not AngularJS 2, and uses the `angular2` tag. The name for AngularJS 1.x is AngularJS and uses the `angularjs` tag. Please edit your question to either remove one of those tags, or explain why both tags are present.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Fixed sir. Trying to do with Angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to pass from json to array you could do the following command:

```
var arr = []
for(i in json_object){
   arr.push(i)
   arr.push(json_object[i])
}
```

Then you have every keys in the even index and every contents in the odd index

Answer (score 0):

Well, I really don't see the point here. Arrays are for operating with lists of similar objects or types, not for complex structures. If you had a bunch of objects similar to the one you show, then it would make sense. Anyways, if you really want an array then you could do it with recursion and create a flat array of the properties.

```
var flatPropertyArray = [];
function flatten(obj) {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof obj[property] == "object")
                flatten(obj[property]);
            else
               flatPropertyArray.push(property);
        }
    }
}
```

pass your JSON into the flatten func.